# SpamAssassin filter header

Tags: email, spamassassin

I'm trying to filter messages with header Return-Path contains string '@example.eu'.

I added to /etc/mail/spamassasin/local.cf this lines:

**My first attempt:**

```
header LOCAL_DEMONSTRATION_ALL  Return-Path =~ /example\.eu/i
score LOCAL_DEMONSTRATION_ALL   10.0
```

**My second attempt:**

```
header LOCAL_DEMONSTRATION_ALL ALL =~ /Return-Path.*example.eu>/i
score LOCAL_DEMONSTRATION_ALL   10.0
```

Another filters work, but this above doesn't. I checked my regex is Ok.

What's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Return-Path` header contains the *Envelope Sender* and is typically added to the email when it is delivered to the recipient's mailbox, i.e. it is not present as a visible header while the email is in transit.

The Envelope Sender is passed in the SMTP dialog using the `MAIL FROM` command and can most often be used in SpamAssassin rules, but depending on exactly how your SpamAssassin is being called the actual details may vary.

SpamAssassin has a pseudo-header `EnvelopeFrom` that it tries to populate with the envelope sender using some heuristics (or you can tell SpamAssassin how it should be populated using the **envelope_sender_header** configuration option). For most setups a rule like this should work:

```
header LOCAL_DEMONSTRATION_ALL  EnvelopeFrom =~ /example\.eu/i
score LOCAL_DEMONSTRATION_ALL   10.0
```